# Unable to use buffer inside ByteData while trying to place a custom text under Marker _icon in Flutter Google Maps Plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am trying to follow the following code in order to create a custom marker in flutter which displays text on my google map markers:

```
Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromCanvas(String text) async {

    final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    final Paint paint1 = Paint()..color = Colors.grey;
    final int size = 100; //change this according to your app
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size / 2, size / 2), size / 2.0, paint1);
    TextPainter painter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    painter.text = TextSpan(
      text: text,//you can write your own text here or take from parameter
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: size / 4, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    );
    painter.layout();
    painter.paint(
      canvas,
      Offset(size / 2 - painter.width / 2, size / 2 - painter.height / 2),
    );

    final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size, size);
    final data = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return data?.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

I am keep getting the following error on the last line where I access the buffer getter inside data which is ByteData:

> The getter 'buffer' isn't defined for the type 'ByteData'. Try
> importing the library that defines 'buffer', correcting the name to
> the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
> 'buffer'.dartundefined_getter

Any idea what am I missing here?

Note I am using flutter SDK "'>=3.1.1 <4.0.0'".

Comment: Hello! Are you importing the class as per the error message?

Comment: Yes of course and still getting the same error message.

Comment: Instead of directly accessing the buffer props, have you tried using the `getter method` `getUint8`? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteData/getUint8.html

Comment: seems to work fine, thank you very much for the help @Yrll !!!!